# UITableView cellForRowAt before numberOfRowsInSection

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

So I have a view controller that has a table view. This view controller has a button that when clicked opens another view controller. There is a button on this view controller that will change the data set for the table view and dismiss the view controller.

Problem is when changing the data set and dismissing the view controller it calls `cellForRowAt`. But because the number of items has the potential to decrease I get an `Index out of range` error.

After setting some break points I realize this is because after updating and dismissing the view controller `cellForRowAt` gets called but `numberOfRowsInSection` doesn't. So the number of rows has updated but that isn't reflected in the table view.

I could do a check in `cellForRowAt` to see if it's out of range before hand and return an empty cell if that's the case, but that seems terribly inefficient. Although it's might be a good idea regardless, in this case seems like such a band-aid fix.

So how can I solve this in an effective and efficient manner?

Comment: anytime you change the "data set" you have to call tableView.reloadData()

Comment: if you show your another view (VC2) as Push or Popup and make changes there with data shown on VC1 and then dismiss VC2 - you have to reload data in viewWillAppear to make changes effect.

Answer (score 2):

There are two solutions to resolve this issue.

1. once the data set is updated just call the [reloadData](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614862-reloaddata) on your tableView which will reload all the data.
2. if some data is deleted then use [deleteRows(at:with:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614960-deleterows) method .

**for single row deletion**

```
data.remove(at: index)
self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
```

**for multiple rows deletion with insertion**

```
 var indexPaths: [IndexPath] = []
 for index in indexArray
   data.remove(at: index)
   indexPaths.append(IndexPath(item: index, section: 0))
 }

 if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
    self.tableView.performBatchUpdates({
       self.tableView.deleteRows(at: indexPaths, with: .fade)
    })
 } else {
     self.tableView.beginUpdates()
     self.tableView.deleteRows(at: indexPaths, with: .fade)
     self.tableView.endUpdates()
 }
```

If you have multiple rows to be removed just create a array of index path with matching row index and pass it to the delete function.

**Edit:**
  use batch updates only for multiple insert/delete/move operations only. as per the  apple docs

UITableView defers any insertions of rows or sections until after it has handled the deletions/insertions of rows or sections. This order is followed regardless how the insertion and deletion method calls are ordered.

Comment: `beginUpdates / endUpdates` is pointless for a single `insert`/`delete`/`move` operation. It's only required for **multiple simultaneous** operations.

Comment: yes the beginUpdates / endUpdates will not be needed for single update

Comment: I assumed multiple row deletion. Edited the answer.

Comment: There is a general misunderstanding. Deleting **multiple** rows is a **single** operation. *Multiple* operations are for example two consecutive lines to insert and delete rows. Those must be wrapped in `begin- / endUpdates`. This is clearly stated in the documentation.

Comment: is multiple rows deletion should be done with beginUpdates/endUpdates call?

Comment: In your example no, crucial are the number of operation **lines**. One line is a single operation, two or more lines are multiple operations. Please have a look at the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/ManageInsertDeleteRow/ManageInsertDeleteRow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH10-SW9)

Comment: Problem with this is it's the data that is being updated is on a separate view controller. Reloading the data on viewWillAppear worked perfectly because of this.

Comment: you can use protocol delegate pattern to pass the data to previous viewcontroller and update the tableview

Answer (score 1):

You can call tableView.reloadData in viewWillAppear method. So it will again reload full tableview with new data.